# Fire Bootstrap popover at cursor x location?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a UI element on a page which is basically a 10000px+ wide scrolling panel inside a viewport. (Think "TV Guide") The scrolling panel consists of a number of "channels" in the form of rows, within which sit relatively positioned divs (think programmes) - these programmes can obviously be varying lengths, and may be significantly wider than the page.

Each programme has a bootstrap popover bound to it, which fires just fine - the problem is that if the "programme" div is wider than the screen, the popover always fires in the centre of the data-bound div - so may appear off-screen.

Can anybody think of a simple but reliable cross-browser way of making the popover fire at the x-location of the cursor when the <s>click</s> hover event is fired?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add an event handler on the click event and inside your handler do then the check of the x location and fire the popup accordingly positioned.

You could also provide some code snippet to make your problem more clear...

Comment: The code is nested inside a fairly huge function, so I'm not sure how much it would help...

Comment: ...I'm calling the popups using the standard bootstrap notation - ie $(element).popover({options..}) - the issue is that the positioning of the popover is nested down within the tooltip function which this extends.
I'm looking to find a way to pass a parameter, specifying a custom "pos" value down to the tooltip function ideally without customising either the tooltip or popover functions, but I presume that's just not possible - so a customised popover function is acceptable...

Comment: You could create dynamically a css class .popover{...} and then put the coordinates inside and apply the class. using "!important" after the coords values would actually override the coordinates the bootstrap popover is using per default.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was just simpler to edit the tooltip function.